# My sql function deosn't return count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one function written in my sql which returns the count of records based on some id's. But it always returns the value 1950.Here is my query.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`trajectory`@`%` FUNCTION `fn_ReturnAlreadyPlayedGames`(AppId int(11),AppUserid int(11)) 
RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
declare Counting int(11);
set Counting=(
select  count(*)  
from user_sessions
where appid= 5 and appuserid= 41 and status=1);
RETURN Counting;
END
```

I have passed static id's for now.when I run this query as plain sql then it returns 8 rows but inside function it always returns 1950.

Please help me in this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is solved by me.Actually there is a problem with column names and parameter name.Both are same.So, I used table alias for that.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Glad to know that was the problem. Its a good practice to have the parameter names unique from the column names to avoid confusion and scope issues.

Answer (score 0):

there is a little mistake ;)

```
where appid= 5 and appuserid= 41 and status=1);
```

you should replace ***appid*** and ***appuserid*** with your variables

Comment: Are you talking about the numbers to be replaced i.e. 5 and 41.If yes, then for now i just want records according to numbers.

Comment: Yes, with that values your are caming up always the count related to that appid(=5) and appuserid(=41) and that is 1950. When you substitute these values with your parameters then you get tha count of recordsrelated to that parameter values of apopid and userappid

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`trajectory`@`%` FUNCTION `fn_ReturnAlreadyPlayedGames`(AppId int(11),AppUserid int(11)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
declare Counting int(11);
set Counting=(
select  count(*)  from user_sessions
 where appid= AppId and appuserid= AppUserid and status=1) ;
RETURN Counting;
END


It still returns the same result.I have paste the query above with changed parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using the same name for the function parameters and the columns. So use an alias when referring to the columns. Or just rename the function parameters.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fn_ReturnAlreadyPlayedGames(AppId int(11),AppUserid int(11)) 
RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    declare Counting int(11);
    set Counting=(select  count(*) from user_sessions us where us.appid= 5 and us.appuserid= 41 and us.status=1);
    RETURN Counting;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

With the parameters

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION fn_ReturnAlreadyPlayedGames(appid_param int(11),appuserid_param int(11)) 
    RETURNS int(11)
    BEGIN
        declare Counting int(11);
        set Counting=(select  count(*) from user_sessions us where us.appid= appid_param and us.appuserid= appuserid_param and us.status=1);
        RETURN Counting;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```